# How I can display in OpenGL an image using the system color profile?

Tags: c++, opengl, colors

I'm loading a texture using OpenGL like this

```
glTexImage2D(
  GL_TEXTURE_2D,
  0,
  GL_RGBA,
  texture.width,
  texture.height,
  0,
  GL_RGBA,
  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
  texture.pixels.data());
```

The issue is that the color of the image looks different from the one I see when I open the file on the system image viewer.

On the screenshot you can see the yellow on the face displayed on the system image viewer has the color **#FEDE57** but the one that is displayed in the OpenGL window is **#FEE262**

[image: screenshot that shows OpenGL is not displaying color properly]

Is there any flag or format I could use to match the same color calibration?

Displaying this same image as a Vulkan texture looks fine, so I can discard there is not an issue in how I load the image data.

Comment: Might be the [gamma](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Gamma-Correction)?

Comment: I tried `glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB); ` with `GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8` in the internal format of the texture and I get the same result

Comment: Gamma correction is not done automatically. You need to do the correction either when reading the image or in the shader based on the gamma value stored in the image inforamtion.

Comment: @t.niese how I can do that?

Comment: Without knowing how you read the data to `texture.pixels'`(the whole process of retrieving the image data form the file) it is not possible to tell if you do something wrong there.  And `GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8` should only be used if the data you read from the image is in the SRGB color space. Using `glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB)` does not mean that you have to use `GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8`. The internal format just says in which format the texture data is so that OpenGL can convert it correctly from sRGB to the linear color spaces in the shader.

Answer (score 1):

In the end it seems like the framebuffer in OpenGL doesn't gets color corrected, so you have to tell the OS to do it for you

```
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

void prepareNativeWindow(SDL_Window *sdlWindow)
{
  SDL_SysWMinfo wmi;
  SDL_VERSION(&wmi.version);
  SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(sdlWindow, &wmi);
  NSWindow *win = wmi.info.cocoa.window;
  [win setColorSpace:[NSColorSpace sRGBColorSpace]];
}
```

I found this solution here https://github.com/google/filament/blob/main/libs/filamentapp/src/NativeWindowHelperCocoa.mm

Answer (score 0):

@Tokenyet and @t.niese are pretty much correct.

You need to approximately power you final colour's `rgb` values by `1.0/2.2`. Something on the line of this:

`FragColor.rgb = pow(fragColor.rgb, vec3(1.0/gamma)); //gamma --> float = 2.2`

Note: this should be the **final/last statement** in the fragment shader. Do all your lighting and colour calculations before this, or else the result will be weird because you will be mixing `linear` and `non-linear` lighting (calculations).

The reason you need to do gamma correction is because the human eye perceives colour differently to what the computer outputs.

[image]

If the light intensity (lux) increases by twice the amount, your eye indeed sees it twice as bright. However, the actual brightness, when increased by twice the amount, increases in a logarithmic (or exponential?, *someone please correct me here*) relationship. The constant of proportionality between the two lighting spaces is `^2.2` (or `^(1.0/2.2)` if you want to go the inverse (which is what you are looking for.)).

For more info: Look at this great [tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Gamma-Correction) on gamma correction!

**Note 2: This is an approximation. Each computer, program, API have their own auto gamma correction method. You system image viewer may have different gamma correction methods (or not even have any for that matter) compared to OpenGL**

**Note 3: Btw, if this does not work, there are manual methods to adjust the colour in the fragment shader, if you know.**

#FEDE57 = RGB(254, 222, 87)

which converted into OpenGL colour coordinates is,

(254, 222, 87) / 255 = `vec3(0.9961, 0.8706, 0.3412)`

Comment: It seems like if I change the profile of the image to be the same of my monitor then the image looks good so. If I do gamma correction in the shader the output will be different depending on the color profile of the loaded image

Comment: Thats true, again referring back to `Note 2` in my answer. If you are still unhappy with the results, look at `Note 3`, which might help, and good luck!

Comment: but adjusting in the shader will be not correct, it dependes on the color profile of the image right?

Comment: @t.niese and you know how this conversion can be done? I really can't find anything about this

Comment: @ellipticaldoor Sorry for the late reply, there might be method. You want the colour #FEDE57 which is `vec3(0.9961, 0.8706, 0.3412)`, right? First you have to find the constant of proportionality between the gamma correction: So put your colour,  `vec3(0.9961, 0.8706, 0.3412)` into the fragment shader `-->` OpenGL Gamma Corrects in its own way `-->` OpenGL outputs colour `-->` check the colour's `rgb / hex` values and find a comparison to your original colour (the **proportionality constant**).

Comment: @ellipticaldoor To continue, because I did not have enough characters remaining, now **power** or **multiply** (depending on how you got it) your `vec3(0.9961, 0.8706, 0.3412)` by `1.0 / proportionality constant` before outputting it into the fragment shader, and it should work. This is because OpenGL will gamma correct it again but this because you have levelled the constant, you should get your original `rgb` value.

Answer (score 0):

Both images and displays have a gamma value.

If `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB` is not enabled then:

> the system assumes that the color written by the fragment shader is in whatever colorspace the image it is being written to is. Therefore, no colorspace correction is performed.

( [khronos: Framebuffer - Colorspace](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer#Colorspace) )

So in that case you need to figure out what the gamma value of the image you read in is and what the one of the output medium is and do the corresponding conversion between those.

To get the one of the output medium is however not always easy.

Therefore it is preferred to enable `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB`

> If `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB` is enabled however, then if the **destination** image is in the sRGB colorspace […], then it will assume the **shader's output** is in the linear RGB colorspace. It will therefore convert the output from linear RGB to sRGB.

( [khronos: Framebuffer - Colorspace](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer#Colorspace) )

So in that case you only need to ensure that the colors you set in the fragment shader don't have gamma correction applied but are linear.

So what you normally do is to get the gamma information of the image, which is done with a certain function of the library you use to read the image.

If the gamma of the image you read is `gamma` you can calculate the value to invert it with `inverseGamme = 1. / gamma`, and then you can use `pixelColor.channel = std::pow(pixelColor.channel, inverseGamme)` for each of the color channels and each pixel to make the color space linear.

You will use this values in the linear color space as texture data.

You could also use something like `GL_SRGB8` for the texture, but then you would need to convert the values of the pixels you read form the image to sRGB colorspace, which roughly is done by first linearizing it and then applying a gamma of `2.2`

Comment: It seems like my issue is that in mac OpenGL is not color corrected, so it doesn't matter what I do to correct the gamma. What matter is the color calibration of the monitor and the one in the image

Comment: @ellipticaldoor if you enable `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB` (also on macOS)  and output the data in the fragment shader in the linear color space,  then this color will be converted by openGL to sRGB color which then will be displayed according to the settings of the OS/Display. So if you open the image in an image viewer that does follow the correct color correction, and you linearized the image colors when you read it into your application and use that linearized colors for your texture, then the images should look the same.

Comment: I'm already doing this but the color correction doesn't get applied

Comment: But even if I correct the gamma of the image, is only going to work in one monitor right? The gamma correction will be different on every screen

Comment: @ellipticaldoor If you open the image in an image viewer and in OpenGL on one PC then those should look identical when they are displayed on the same monitor. If you open the image in an image viewer on one PC and show them on different displays then those might look different. And the same is true if viewed on different PCs. If all displays are calibrated the same way, and you have ideal conditions, then those images should look identical on all displays, even if they are on different PCs. But that is ture for any image processing program, software, game, and not related to openGL.